# MSSQL 2005 C# Assembly & output

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, assemblies

I'm having a problem outputting a variable in my assembly.

1. Do I need to add a `out string var1` to the parameter list of the function in C#?
   I get an error - something related to `var1` not being set...
2. I tried `parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`
3. I can't find any good examples

Edit:
My assembly SP currently returns a recordset... I want it to output some variables so that I can use them in another SP where this is called from.

I.E.

```
DECLARE @var1 int
EXEC dbo.MyAssemblySP @var1 OUTPUT
PRINT @var1
```

Comment: You cannot output (or input) a variable from an assembly, only methods. Please rephrease you question.
Are you talking about parametrised SQL statements and ADO.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to use the `out` keyword, here is the proper syntax:

```
public void foo(int arg1, out int arg2) {
    arg2 = arg1;
}

public void foo2() {
    int aOutput;
    foo(1, out aOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(aOutput);
}
```

Calling `foo2` will result in the console writing `1`.